# Ruby on Rails 3: link_to create new nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a link to create a new nested resource in my Rails 3 application, but I can't figure it out. What is the syntax to link to a new nested resource

### Solution:

Make sure you have your resources properly nested in your routes file.

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters
end
```

Then in your view script you can call it like this:

```
<%= link_to 'New Chapter', new_book_chapter_path(@book) %>
```

[The Rails Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) was quite helpful.

*Note:* if you get a message like `Couldn't find Book without an ID`, the problem isn't the link, it's the code in your controller.

```
def new
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id]) #instead of :id
  @chapter = @book.chapter.new
  respond_with(@chapter)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make changes in routes as

```
map.resources :books do |book|
    book.resources :chapters
end
```

and then use this

```
link_to new_book_chapter_path(@book)
```

You can also use this link to understand the concept better
[Nested Routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: You can skip block arguments, i.e. `|map|` and `|book|`.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I was doing it right, but my bug was in a different area of my code.