# Rails new action attempting show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm starting a new Rails 3.2.6 application. My nested route is failing when I attempt to view the new nested form. I'll first show the error, then all of the code involved.

URL attempting to access: `http://localhost:3000/reports/1/expenses/new`

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"expenses", :report_id=>#<Report id: 1, name: "Test Report", created_at: "2012-06-07 21:58:37", updated_at: "2012-06-07 21:58:37">}
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :reports do
  resources :expenses
end
```

**expenses_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
  @expense = @report.expenses.new
end
```

**views/expenses/new.html.haml**

```
%h1 New Expense
= render 'form'
```

**views/expenses/_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for [@report, @expense] do |f|
```

This is the link I'm attempting to click:

```
= link_to 'New Expense', new_report_expense_path(@report)
```

I can't figure out why it's trying to access the show action when I'm explicitly calling the new action.

**Rake Routes**

```
report_expenses     GET    /reports/:report_id/expenses(.:format)          expenses#index
                    POST   /reports/:report_id/expenses(.:format)          expenses#create
new_report_expense  GET    /reports/:report_id/expenses/new(.:format)      expenses#new
edit_report_expense GET    /reports/:report_id/expenses/:id/edit(.:format) expenses#edit
report_expense      GET    /reports/:report_id/expenses/:id(.:format)      expenses#show
                    PUT    /reports/:report_id/expenses/:id(.:format)      expenses#update
                    DELETE /reports/:report_id/expenses/:id(.:format)      expenses#destroy
        reports     GET    /reports(.:format)                              reports#index
                    POST   /reports(.:format)                              reports#create
     new_report     GET    /reports/new(.:format)                          reports#new
    edit_report     GET    /reports/:id/edit(.:format)                     reports#edit
         report     GET    /reports/:id(.:format)                          reports#show
                    PUT    /reports/:id(.:format)                          reports#update
                    DELETE /reports/:id(.:format)                          reports#destroy
           root            /                                               reports#index
```

**UPDATE**
Link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/ardavis/expense_report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the views/expences/_form.html.haml, last line

```
      = link_to 'Cancel', report_expense_path(@report), class: 'btn'
```

You probably meant

```
      = link_to 'Cancel', report_path(@report), class: 'btn'
```

Comment: This is a great example of where the Rails stack trace is a lot more useful than it seems. Near to the error message there will have been a file name and line number which would pointed you to this line, and not the one you thought was wrong

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Where do you see the stack trace though? The only error I see is the "routing error", with nothing below it to view the trace. Feel free to clone the repo and try yourself. I'm not sure what methods I should have used to track it down.

Comment: With such errors Rails does not show the trace in the browser, only in server console. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in routes:

```
map.resources :reports do |report|
    report.resources :expenses
end
```

Comment: Ah nm, that's wrong too.. you've done it right as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put @report.id instead of @report in your link

```
link_to 'New Expense', new_report_expense_path(@report.id)
```

Comment: As much as I wish this was the solution, it is not. I've done this before, and I know it's not needed. And I've attempted your solution, and it gives the exact same error, no difference at all.

Comment: Darn. Sorry about that. I just don't get why the whole object is attempting to pass for id. But I guess that's normal and that rails picks the id from it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a custom route which accepts :id as a param?  Maybe match "/expenses/new/:id" => "expenses#new"

Comment: I have not. This is the strangest thing I've ever seen. I've been working with Rails for about 2 years, and I've done nested routing before. Rake Routes even shows that this should work :(

Comment: Well, it'd be better to figure out the correct answer to your question, but in the mean time you could do the custom route. It should work that way.

Comment: What seems like a million times :)

Comment: Ok, deleted that then.. I can't figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to put it on github and provide a link to the repo in a few minutes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775531/ruby-on-rails-3-link-to-create-new-nested-resource

Comment: There's a comment in that, that mentions "Thanks. I realized that I was doing it right, but my bug was in a different area of my code.". So I don't think it's my routes file. I just posted a link to the git repo if you wish to clone it.

Comment: @Abram in response to "why the whole object is attempting to pass for id" - Rails use "to_param" on object, which in turn return "id". If you want to create friendly urls, most of the time you just need to override this method in models